# If I use IN operator to filter NULL values and white spaces It is not working Why?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like
table1(id int,name VC,description VC);
This table contains 100s of records. For description column it has some white spaces and null values I want to eliminate the rows for which the description value is Null or whitespace?

I tried in this way

```
select * from table1 where description not in('',NULL); //Displaying nothing

But

select * from table1 where description in('',NULL);// It is displaying all the rows which contains white spaces but not Nulls
```

I am confused. IN operator accepts varchar also, I am getting correct result if I wont use NOT, but Why I am not getting If I use NOt.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `select * form table1` is incorrect. should be `select * from table1`

Comment: from my tests neither of your queries work for the `NULL` part. You may need to check what results you are getting. Using `NULL` within an `IN` never matches any field with a `NULL` for me. As other posters have stated `NULL` is treated as a special case operator and should be used with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use IS NOT NULL to compare null values

```
select * from table1 where description is not null and description <> ''
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`select * from table1 where description not in('') and description is not null`;

Comment: You've copied the typo from the OP. `select * FORM table1`

Comment: It is working ,,but could you please explain why it is not giving correct result if I use IN('',NULL). Actually it is the purpose of IN to use multiple values and to reduce multiple OR s.

Comment: Yes, it is the purpose of In to give multiple values..But null is a special case, and needs to be handled specially. So when comparing logic is Not, then for nulls we need to used "is not null"

Answer (score 0):

Because the SQL "IN" condition helps reduce the need to use multiple SQL "OR" conditions.

So, writing:

```
description not in('',NULL);
```

it's the same to:

```
!(description='' OR description is NULL)
```

Thant it's the same to write:

```
!(description='') AND description is not NULL
```

Comment: @Chella nops, we cant compare null with equality sign.

Comment: Yes..I got it now. Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

Could try this - this will be similar to c# .IsNullOrWhitespace

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Description IS NOT NULL AND LEN(TRIM(Description) > 0)