# NOT IN Operator is not working for non-primary key values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have read many Q&A's regarding NOT IN operator i.e
[If I use IN operator to filter NULL values and white spaces It is not working Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740648/if-i-use-in-operator-to-filter-null-values-and-white-spaces-it-is-not-working-wh)
and many others, But the problem is that when we use not in operator for non-primary key, it is not returning the response.

```
SELECT * FROM temp_customers WHERE temp_customers.fk_my_id NOT IN (SELECT fk_my_id FROM customers)
```

Where fk_my_id is non-primary key and might be a string.

Any Idea please?

Comment: would you mind to post what the error occuring?

Comment: which error  or exception u have got?

Comment: @kaii: their are three entries that would came, but not a single row is returng :(

Comment: Can you provide sample data from both tables, and expected result ?

Comment: @gotson: group_concat is working for this, thanks you please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `group_concat` here for separating `fk_my_id` with comma

```
SELECT * FROM temp_customers WHERE temp_customers.fk_my_id NOT IN 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fk_my_id) FROM customers)   
# when fk_my_id is INTEGER output (1,2)

SELECT * FROM temp_customers WHERE temp_customers.fk_my_id NOT IN 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("'",fk_my_id,"'") FROM customers)   
# when fk_my_id is VARCHAR output ('1','2')
```

Comment: b.t.w what was the issue please, please would you help some one else too?

Comment: @john The problem was that the `fk_my_id` was not separated with comma and resulting only one string, but with the help of `GROUP_CONCAT` your all id's are separated with comma.

Comment: agree with that but I wonder why in MYSQL IN() is it already seperated by comma while in NOT IN() it is not..

Comment: I have no idea why this got 6 votes but it does not do what you think. The concatenated value will get cast to an INT and you will get all temp customers with id != the first id from customers. I tested it with `select * from test where id not in (select group_concat(id) from test)` - it returns all rows except the 1-st.

Comment: @Vatev: hmmmm you are using the same table in sub-query, so might be this problem, but if you have two separate tables then, group_concat is working excellently. :)

Comment: With group_concat you actually get `... IN('1,2,3,4')` instead of `... IN(1,2,3,4)`. Also tried it with another table - same result.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar +1 for always give simple & perfect answer.

Comment: @Vatev: exactly, In my scenario, their might be a fk_my_id would be a string or an integer, so that was the best to use the group_concat.

Comment: So you will get `... IN ('1,apples,oranges')` instead of `... IN (1,'apples','oranges')`

Comment: With `GROUP_CONCAT("'",fk_my_id,"'")` it will be equivalent to running `... IN("'1','2','3'")` which will still be treated as a single string which happens to have some quotes and commas inside.

Comment: You might wanna test that one.

Answer (score 0):

I my guess you have used wrong column in query: `(SELECT fk_my_id FROM customers)` . It should be pkId of your customer table

```
SELECT * FROM temp_customers 
WHERE temp_customers.fk_my_id 
NOT IN (SELECT pk_my_id FROM customers)
```